# ASP.NET MVC with Amazon cloudfront - YSlow grade F for cookile-free domains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, yslow

I am using the Amazon Cloudfront CDN to serve the assets for an ASP.NET MVC website. When I analyze my site using YSlow I get an F grade for *Use cookie-free domains*. It specifically indicates that the assets hosted on Cloudfront are the culprits with urls like the following (this is not a real asset) being flagged:

https://mywebsiteassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Images/back.png

Is there a way to make Cloudfront cookie-free? Does this need to be done on client or server level?

Thank you

JP

Answer (score 2):

This warning suggests that you are using single domain (eg example.com) to host your website - both dynamic and static resources. Presumably, you also created CloudFront distribution to speed up content delivery. I will refer to it as d123.cloudfront.net

When users authorize at your website (you did not say this explicitly, but I think this is most expected scenario when server sets some browser cookies), your browser saves session ID (or similar) cookie and will send it back to server upon each request. Your server then uses that cookie to authenticate user and let him access private content section.

You don't usually need to authorize access to the static resources, such as images, CSS and JavaScript files. However, browser will still sent cookies when requesting such resources, wasting few bytes of client (and server) bandwidth.

What you want to do is to separate your static and dynamic resources. You may, for example, set up separate CloudFront distribution (say, d999.cloudfront.net) to deliver your images. Browser will not send cookies I tented for authentication on d123.cloudfront.net while requesting images from d999.cloudfront.net.

Comment: I can get the idea about a separate sub-domain to serve cookie-free static content, but not sure about how can I do those setting in cloudfront....
can you give us some hint on this matter?